# Error after uninstalling ionic 2 loadash module

Tags: npm, ionic2, node-modules

I ran the command `npm install --save loadash`

Then I tried to uninstalling it with the command `npm uninstall --save loadash`

but after that when I tried to run the app using `ionic serve` the following error is thrown. What to do?

```
 Cannot find module 'lodash/assign'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/HybridApps/ayrll/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/index.js:5:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/HybridApps/ayrll/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/index.js:14:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
```

Comment: have you used that function somewhere in your code?

Comment: I did but then I removed it.

Comment: check the code.. You may have missed removing it somewhere..maybe overlooked an import..

Comment: ok. let me check

Comment: Nope. I don't think so.

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1402

Answer (score 0):

```
 Cannot find module 'lodash/assign'
```

Means it is looking for lodash `assign` somewhere in your code base.

There is one major issue with this command `npm uninstall --save loadash` , what is "loadash"? it should be "lodash", but besides that if lodash has been removed from your `package.json` it wont remove any references that are in the code based.

You should do a full search for `assign` in your code. If there is no results then i would recommend completing a fresh `ionic serve` to rebuild the project.

Comment: I didn't find anything named assign in my project. I didn't get the fresh ionic serve thing. Please help.

Comment: are you looking for lodash or loadash, because there is a major difference between the two? I dont know what you mean by "I didnt get the fresh ionic serve thing". the error says there is an assignment of lodash/assign  somewhere, there is no two ways of getting around that. Its there you just need to find it. It might be that you have installed a 3rd party lib that relies on lodash

Comment: Well then you have uninstalled nothing because there is no package called loadash. You can check to see if lodash still exists in you `package.json` or in your `node_modules` folder

Comment: I reinstalled lodash. To see what happens. Then I got the error :  typescript: node_modules/@types/lodash/index.d.ts